# Fitting Gaussian to specific data

Tags: matlab, statistics, gaussian, model-fitting

```
52.3210481666667    52.3841781666667    52.4938248333333    52.6234071666667    52.9058301666667    53.2846095000000    53.8162295000000    54.4442056666667    55.2349903333333    56.0556786666667    56.9660778333333    57.8731546666667    58.7802311666667    59.6142101666667    60.4249306666667    61.1559080000000    61.7971748333333    62.3387626666667    62.8205433333333    63.2259036666667    63.4950361666667    63.7807816666667    63.9203320000000    64.0964311666667    64.1794968333334    64.2625625000000    64.3323375000000    64.3888223333333    64.5117591666667    64.5017913333333    64.6147606666667    64.6878583333334    64.7476660000000    64.8307311666667    64.9038291666667    65.0334115000000    65.1131545000000    65.2261236666667    65.2792856666667    65.3789643333333    65.4387716666667    65.5052241666667    65.5417731666667    65.5949351666667    65.6248388333333    65.6181933333333    65.6580648333333    65.6181935000000    65.6115481666667    65.5716766666667    65.4985790000000    65.4321263333333    65.3291250000000    65.2394141666667    65.1065091666667    64.9470231666667    64.7709240000000    64.5715665000000    64.3622411666667    64.0764953333333    63.7342651666667    63.3920346666667    62.9899973333333    62.6078951666667    62.1460503333333    61.7207541666667    61.2987811666667    60.9166793333333    60.5478676666667    60.2355410000000    59.9398273333333    59.7703733333333    59.5809840000000    59.5112088333333    59.4281431666667    59.3949168333333    59.4015621666667    59.3616906666667    59.3683361666667    59.3749811666667    59.3384323333333    59.2786250000000    59.2088498333333    59.0825901666667    59.0194603333333    58.8998458333333    58.7270695000000    58.5875188333333    58.4213878333333    58.2619016666667    58.1123836666667    57.9263165000000    57.7535401666667    57.6239576666667    57.4644718333333    57.3382118333333    57.1886940000000    57.0757245000000    56.9162386666667    56.8032695000000    56.6869775000000    56.5540725000000    56.4278128333333    56.3381018333333    56.1885838333333    56.1354216666667    56.0025168333333    55.9493546666667    55.8330628333333    55.7666103333333    55.6835448333333    55.6337053333333    55.5008003333333    55.4509610000000    55.3778633333333    55.2748616666667    55.2117321666667    55.1519248333333    55.0688591666667    54.9990840000000    54.9060503333333    54.8462431666667    54.7731455000000    54.6767891666667    54.6003690000000    54.5239486666667    54.4309151666667    54.3711078333333    54.2946873333333    54.1883635000000    54.1352015000000    54.0454905000000    53.9458116666667    53.9059403333333    53.8261973333333    53.7464543333333    53.6932923333333    53.6069041666667    53.5504195000000    53.5437741666667    53.4308048333333    53.3510618333333    53.3045453333333    53.2646738333333    53.1882535000000    53.1184781666667    53.0752840000000    53.0453805000000    52.9756055000000    52.9091530000000    52.8726038333333    52.8227646666667    52.7563121666667    52.7064725000000    52.6699238333333    52.5802131666667    52.5835355000000    52.5037928333333    52.4572760000000    52.4107590000000    52.3675648333333    52.3144033333333    52.2811766666667    52.2512731666667    52.2114015000000    52.1682075000000    52.1482715000000    52.1283358333333    52.1150456666667    52.0353025000000    52.0353025000000    52.0186893333333    51.9489141666667
```

From upper data, I want to extract gaussian function formula. Gaussian function formula is y=A*exp(-(x-τ)^2/σ^2)  (A is amplitude, τ is phase, σ is width). From upper data, I know A is 13.7092 (max-min value) and τ is 47. However, I don't know σ. I already calculate σ as standard deviation. But the value is not fit. Is there any function in matlab to extract function formula? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/11733-gaussian-curve-fit

Comment: The mean and standard deviation are all you need.

Since all of your data values are larger than 50, I don't understand how you could get a mean of 47.  How did you calculate that value?

Answer (score 6):

Matlab has a built in function:

```
    [mu,sigma] = normfit(data)
```

But I don't see why you think it is Gaussian distribution - look at the histogram:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Transform the gaussian function using natural logarithm to a linear equation. Find the least square solution with [mldivide](http://www.mathworks.ch/help/techdoc/ref/mldivide.html).

```
bb = (T-x).^2;
AA = log(y)-log(A);
xx = AA\bb;

sprintf('%f',sqrt(abs(xx)))
```